# Can every chemical compound be melted?

Tags: phase, temperature, melting-point

Are there any chemical compounds that disintegrate (without going into other chemical reactions; let's say in a vacuum) before reaching a melting temperature?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62539/why-all-objects-do-not-melt-and-liquefy-when-heated-suficiently also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31050/can-you-melt-wood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some compounds decompose before they reach the melting point. In the literature, you'll see something like "m.p. $40\ ^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ (dec.)"

[Ammonium chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_chloride) is an example.

Comment: + Sugars, proteins, and a lot of others. Some of these can be molten under pressure.